# Can a RAM calculate its own Gödel number?

Tags: computability

You can get the Gödel number of a RAM by making it a list of commands and making this list an integer.

So, what I thought is something like "The RAM that would return its own Gödel number (say, $x$) would have to have the information $x$ in it, so the integer would be greater than $x$, so it would not return its own Gödel number."

But then I noticed that for specific numbers you could do compressing, such as calculating $10^{9999}$ instead of writing 100000...000 in the code of the RAM. Probably the Gödel number would not be $10^{9999}$ though, but at least it *could* be.

**Question:** Is there a RAM that calculates its own Gödel number? Can there be such?

Comment: By the way, palsch, here's a cool [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAja2jp1VjE) about your user icon. :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherb These are not only pixels but the Ulam spiral. I programmed this some time ago for my math teacher. Purple pixels are prime twins, red ones are other primes and the orange pixel in the middle is 1. :-)

Comment: Nice! So here's a [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFuR97YcSLM) that's literally about your user icon! :-D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consider the computable function $Q\colon \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ given by $Q(x,y) = x$.  By [Kleene's second recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem#Kleene.27s_second_recursion_theorem), there is some $p$ such that the program with Gödel number $p$ computes the function $f(y) = Q(p,y)=p$, i.e., a program which outputs $p$ for every input. This is exactly the program you're looking for: for any input, it outputs its own Gödel number.

Such a program is known as a [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29), and they exist in any Turing-powerful model of computation.

Comment: Can you be sure to run this program in the limited memory of the ram? I suppose here RAM means random access memory...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson No, it refers to a [Random-Access Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine), a Turing-powerful model of computation.